# Plugins for Browser?

Tags: browser

Are there any plugins or extensions(Free or proprietary) for the new browser that I can add to make it work more efficiently ?

Comment: do you mean the browser App that comes with Ubuntu trusty ?

Comment: Yes exactly I love the Interface and I want to use it more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webbrowser-app does not support plugins yet.